# How to use scalamock for the awssdk

Tags: scala, aws-sdk, scalamock

I have a function that has the following type signature:

```scala
def post(target: String, partition: String, payload: String): IO[Boolean]
```

In this function, a call is placed to a third party to post this data to a service through the `awssdk`. For testing, I don't want these calls actually placed, which has brought me to scalamock, but am not sure how to do this in looking at the documentation.

Within the post function I have leverage my private instance of aws's client for this service after setting credentials. There is a particular method on this instance that is responsible for the call to aws.

How can scalamock be leveraged to mock the awssdk to test the code I have surrounding this and not make the actual call?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a trait that defines this method? Then you can use Scalamock to get an instance of it and make it respond to `post` calls with whatever value you want it to.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KgJ0kptnRaiteNTWPBzrow

```scala
trait MyService {
  def post(target: String, partition: String, payload: String): Future[Boolean]
}

  
val mockedService = mock[MyService]
  
(mockedService.post _)
  .expects("a", "b","c")
  .returning(Future.successful(true))
  .once()

mockedService.post("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: This would work well if I wanted to mock out this point, but was hoping to instead test the code in `post` and mock out the awssdk to ensure that the wrapping code is doing the expected behavior.

Comment: Well, same idea. Where you call the AWSSDK from inside `post`, call a mock AWSSDK instead (that you have injected into the service that implements `post`). I assume there is a `trait` (or Java interface) that defines those methods on AWSSDK?

Comment: From everything I've found, you leverage things as found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html) -- namely, reference the service client, call `builder` and configure it followed by `build`. You then interact with this instance. Seems the client definition is an interface, but if trying to leverage this interface like a trait there are strange things that start happening (I can adapt the code to compile, but then it throws errors). Not sure that is the right way to go given the examples I've seen either.